# meaning of javascript sign $?

Tags: javascript, function

scuse me , what does that mean inside of a javascript program text

```
console.log(`${ingredientAmount} ${unit} ${name}`); ?
```

This is the textprogram containing the line mentioned before:

```js
const hummus = function(factor) {
  const ingredient = function(amount, unit, name) {
    let ingredientAmount = amount * factor;
    if (ingredientAmount > 1) {
      unit += "s";
    }
    console.log(`${ingredientAmount} ${unit} ${name}`);
  };
  ingredient(1, "can", "chickpeas");
  ingredient(0.25, "cup", "tahini");
  ingredient(0.25, "cup", "lemon juice");
  ingredient(1, "clove", "garlic");
  ingredient(2, "tablespoon", "olive oil");
  ingredient(0.5, "teaspoon", "cumin");
};
```

Comment: It says it right in that message: separate blocks of code by blank lines and indent 4 spaces.

Comment: These are ES6's template literals.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Those are [template literals/string templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

That's a [template literal / template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), the `${` and `}` are the tokens to define placeholders that would be replaced by the value of the expression inside them.

So this:

```
console.log(`${ ingredientAmount } ${ unit } ${ name }`);
```

With a normal `string` would be:

```
console.log(ingredientAmount + ' ' + unit + ' ' + name);
```

Comment: *"That's a template literal/string"* No, it's a template literal (no "/string"). When it's evaluated without a tag function, it produces a string. But when used with a tag function, the result isn't necessarily a string.

Comment: They were called `template strings` in previous versions of the specification, so it's still worth mentioning both names as there are resources available that call them like that. For example: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

Comment: Anyway, it might be confusing the way it was written. Now it should be clearer.

Comment: They weren't called template strings in any of the specifications, going back to ES2015 (it's unfortunate Addy Osmani made that mistake in that article). Perhaps early on in the strawman, but only early on. The less people call them "template strings," the better for comprehension...

Comment: The first attempt to ask something on stackoverflow = the first bann in asking more questions. That is a help from one-billion-medals-guys to a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

`${}` in Javascript's ES6 world signals Javascript that while parsing that literal, it's going to find an `expression` to  evaluate inside the curly brackets, which means that when creating a `String` from the template literal, these parts are going to be replaced by whatever value the expression inside evaluates to at the time of parsing. Backticks  enclose the template literal:

```
`** literal here**`
```

The expression can not only be variables like shown by you, it could as well be something other like

```
`Today's date is ${new Date()}. Have a beautiful day!`
```

or

```
`The random number of the moment is ${Math.random()}.`
```